# Error 403 github

Tags: git, github

Criei um nova conta no GitHub e quando eu tento dar um `git push -u origin master` ele retorna um erro dizendo que eu não tenho permissão para acessar aquele repositório. Aparece como que se o minha antiga conta tivesse tentando acessar esse repositório. Tentei mudar usando `git config user.name "Antonio Matheus"` e também com `git config user.email "antoniomatheushs@gmail.com"`. Mas mesmo assim o erro persiste.

O erro aparece assim:

> remote: permission to antoniomatheush/pomodoro-timer-site.git denied
>   to maggrilmur. fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.com/antoniomatheush/pomodoro-timer-site.git/': The
>   requested URL returned error: 403

`maggrilmur` é o nome de usuário da minha conta antiga no GitHub, `antoniomatheush` é a que eu criei recentemente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O usuário e senha do commit não tem relação com a parte de autenticação no Github.

Provavelmente o Windows está tentando usar suas antigas credenciais. Você pode confirmar isto com o comando:

```
git config credential.helper
```

Para [alterar isto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46629838/unable-to-change-git-account), você precisa ir no **Gerenciador de Credenciais** do Windows. Lá, procure por uma entrada parecida com `git.https://github.com`. Edite ele colocando seu novo usuário Github e senha. Depois disto, tente novamente fazer o *push*.

Comment: Salvou minha vida, valeu.